# Failed building wheel for pyarrow (cmake error)

Tags: cmake, streamlit, pyarrow

Am not able to solve this error, at first thought that it was python version error so downgraded to 3.6 but still not able to do it.

```
PS D:\Emo> pip install streamlit
Collecting streamlit
  Using cached streamlit-1.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 MB)
Collecting pydeck>=0.1.dev5
  Using cached pydeck-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.1 in d:\codrs\python 3.7\lib\site-packages (from streamlit) (21.3)
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
      -- Running CMake for PyArrow C++
      cmake -DARROW_BUILD_DIR=build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\GAURIP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1g509rj0\pyarrow_a9950c5da511498d9e85239311ed4fd7\build\dist "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=d:\codrs\python 3.7\python.exe" "-DPython3_EXECUTABLE=d:\codrs\python 3.7\python.exe" -DPYARROW_CXXFLAGS= -DPYARROW_WITH_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_WITH_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_WITH_HDFS=off -G "Visual 
Studio 15 2017 Win64" C:\Users\GAURIP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1g509rj0\pyarrow_a9950c5da511498d9e85239311ed4fd7\pyarrow/src
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "d:\codrs\python 3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
          "__main__", mod_spec)
        File "d:\codrs\python 3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
          exec(code, run_globals)
        File "D:\Codrs\python 3.7\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      error: command 'D:\\Codrs\\python 3.7\\Scripts\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Following fix were tried:
1. install cmake separately but it shows same error
2. install different version of streamlit was able to bypass the cmake step but not able to use further streamlit-webrts as it requires pyarrow which requires cmake

Comment: Please, incorporate all relevant information about your problem into the **question post** (via [edit]). *Comments* are used only for *request* additional details, not for provide them.